# Use local server of Mac on iPhone

Tags: ios, macos, server, osx-yosemite

I'm trying to make an app that sends data to server attaching it to the URL. I have a ruby code running on my local server. I tried using iOS simulator and it works fine. Now I want to try using my iPhone and send data to the Mac local server. How should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your mac and your iPhone are using same internet connection, and use IP of your mac instead of localhost. It wont work if you are using cellular network